# Does google-people api provide a callback to determine when the contact list changes?

Tags: google-people-api

Other Google services provide a way to register a callback to be called when some server-side data changes.  E.G. Email.

I'm wondering if the google-people API provides such a feature?

If now, how often is it acceptable to poll this API to determine if the list has changed?

Thanks

Comment: Could you please give an example of what's the behaviour expected? Or the Google API you are using to get the callback?

Comment: When a new contact is added i would like to get a callback. This way I would not need to poll the connection.

Comment: By "callback to determine when the contact list changes" you mean notifications like Gmail [push notifications](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/push?hl=ro#overview)?

Comment: Yes a push notification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not push notification service in the People API yet. As a workaround If you mean to make polling requests there's a quota limit per minute per user defined in [your project](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/people.googleapis.com/quotas), it's flexible depending on your configuration. If you have a specific user to make long-polling make sure the API has the enough quota limit.